# SQLAlchemy lost connection to Database when I am accessing model's property

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

python 2.7.10
SQLAlchemy 1.2.15

I have a model like this

```
class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))
```

if there will be a lot of time between getting an object and accessing its property I can get an exception

```
obj = SomeClass.objects.get(11)
sleep(10000) # Some time passed
print(obj.name)
```

Here I can get an Exception

```
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Is there any way to avoid this Exception?

UPD: I don't understand why it needs a connection to DB when it tries to get property from `obj` even if `obj` was received before???

Comment: You need to determine why the connection is being closed.  Is it being closed in your code?  Does the time exceed the timeouts in the [session settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html)?  Are there intervening firewalls that will drop inactive connections?

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's for sure not because of my code. Because everything works if main code takes less than 5 minutes